# How to Create Timeline with Dynamic Start/End Dates

Tags: website-design, info-visualisation, graphs, timeline

I'm trying to think of an intuitive way to make the the start/end dates changeable for the timeline (x-axis) of this graph.

On mobile this would be easy because you could use pinch to zoom in/out but is there a good way to do it on desktop?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to zoom on a particular range, but still see underlying trends you can use a **timeline scrubber** below the x-axis.

[image]

**[Highcharts](https://www.highcharts.com/stock/demo/candlestick-and-volume)** is a well known library that has this component. You can zoom using direct manipulation, and you can see a macro view of trend volume outside of the zoom window at the same time.

Highcharts refers to this as a **[scrollbar](https://www.highcharts.com/docs/chart-concepts/scrollbar)** in their documentation.